# (RADGrid ItemCommand Event) Cannot Get Values From Cells?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010, telerik-grid, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I am having a strange problem. First let me start by saying that I am using the Telerik controls supplied by DotNetNuke. So I can not "upgrade" to any other version of the Telerik controls. I am stuck with what I am given.

I wrote a module initially using DNN v06.02.09 (Telerik v2012.2.724.35) and it worked great. I unfortunately am forced to upgrade to a newer DNN version because of a bug found in this particular version of Telerick's RADScheduler (which effects the month of November only). So...now I am running DNN v07.00.06 (Telerik v2013.1.403.40). [Note: I also tested this with the most recent DNN v7.04.01 (Telerik v????) and confirmed the same behavior described below]

Previously when I clicked on a button inside the RADGrid and the ItemCommand event fires I was able to obtain the value of each cell in the row that the button was activated in. The same exact code running in DNN v7.x now returns "nbsp;" for every single cell in the row. It's like the new Telerik version doesn't bind the data to the GridDataItem (e.Item) within the ItemCommand event like it used to.

What am I missing? How do I get the selected row's data like I had before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after scouring the internet and trying everything I could think of to fix this...I stumbled across the following "article"... http://www.telerik.com/forums/breaking-change-hidden-column-cell-text-is-not-persisted-in-viewstate

You would think they would make this stuff easier to find. Apparently the ".Visible" property's behavior was changed, so that if the column is not visible, it also does not bind data. They created a new property called ".Display" that would hide the column but still bind the data. I had to change my code to use the new property and then the grid's behavior was returned to what it was previously.